# Mercurial: Can you track changes across a file that has been renamed to another tracked file?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, merge

I know that you can track changes to renamed files from a repo to it's clone. However, I seem to have an issue when I rename a file to a file name that is already being tracked. In essence, I want to copy over a tracked file.

**Files in original repo:**

```
application.txt
special.txt
```

Then clone the repo, delete `application.txt` and rename `special.txt` to be `application.txt`

I would expect that the next time I made changes to `special.txt` in the original repo, the changes would carry over to `application.txt`. However, it doesn't. I get this message

```
local changed special.txt which remote deleted
use (c)hanged version or (d)eleted?
```

Trying this same thing out in Git seems to have the same results. Renaming a file to a brand new name has no issues while trying to rename a file that has already been 'taken' causes conflicts. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Did you tell hg the rename with `hg mv`? Hg does not automatically track file renames, you must explicitly tell hg if you want to rename or copy a file.

Comment: Yes. First I tried `hg rm application.txt` then `hg mv special.txt application.txt`. I've also  tried `hg mv special.txt application.txt -f`. Either way, when doing the next merge, I get conflicts.

Comment: I've also tried a commit after removing `application.txt` then renaming `special.txt`. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I logged a bug on Mercurial's bug tracker. Will update as I learn more. http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/issue2601

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't really call this a bug, as you have for all purposes just changed the contents of a file that mercurial is already tracking. Mercurial tracks files by file name and extension, and you could make the case that this is no different than just replacing the entire contents of the file.

Comment: Agreed. Although it's a bit frustrating that I can't seem to do what I wanted, Mercurial is behaving as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem in a real world project with Mercurial. GIT is also seeing bogus conflicts (special.txt deleted and updated).

Bazaar has proper rename support and it merges this case correctly (changes to special.txt are carried over and application.txt get updated as expected).
The problem with Bazaar though (at least for me) is that it lacks IntelliJ support. There are 2 plugins, the most recent has not been updated for 3 years, and last time i tried it was unusable with recent IntelliJ versions.
Since "bzr mv" and "bzr rename" need to be invoked by the IDE at the time of refactoring, the lack of support makes Bazaar unusable for me.

If you want IntelliJ support for this, vote here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5344